# error handling with object tag HTML to display PDF

Tags: html, safari, mobile-safari

I have 3 questions on this regard

1) is there a way to enforce the response content-type for the object tag.
ie. i send a request to the server for a PDF. however if I receive any repines other than "content-type" as "application/pdf", Id like to display an error.

2) I have received the byte stream from an ajax call to retrieve the PDF.. Is it possible to flush this bytestream to an object tag

3) when exactly does the onerror function get called for the object tag..

The browser I am testing on is Safari.